# Computed Property not firing

Tags: ember.js

I have a computed property `cookieToggle` that I'm using in a LoginController. The basic idea is that it would observe the `username` and `rememberMe` fields and set or clear the username cookie as appropriate. Unfortunately when I update either of the dependant fields it never calls the `cookieToggle` function (as observed by the lack of the console message that every call should produce). My main question is: why not? My secondary question is: is this a reasonable use of Ember's computed property?

```
App.LoginController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    CLIENT_ID: 1,
    username: null,
    password: null,
    rememberMe: false,
    cookieToggle: function() {
        var rememberMe = this.get('rememberMe');
        var username = this.get('username');
        console.log("cookie toggle");
        if (rememberMe) {
            $.cookie('auth_username', username);
        } else {
            $.removeCookie('auth_username');
        }
        return rememberMe;
    }.property('rememberMe','username'),

    init: function() {
        this._super();
        if ($.cookie('auth_username')) {
            this.set('username', $.cookie('auth_username'));
            this.set('rememberMe', true);
        }
    },  

    loginUser: function() {
        var router = this.get('target');
        var data = this.getProperties('username', 'password', 'rememberMe');
        var user = this.get('model');

        $.post('/api/oauth/user_credentials', { username: data.username, password: data.password, client_id: this.get('CLIENT_ID') }, function(results) {
            // App.AuthManager.authenticate(results.api_key.access_token, results.api_key.user_id);
            console.log(results);
            $.cookie('auth_user', results.user.id);
            router.transitionTo('users/login');
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A computed property is not the right decision in this case. You want to use an `Observer`. You even use this verb yourself, right? :-) Just change your declaration from `property` to `observes` :

```
cookieToggle: function() {
        var rememberMe = this.get('rememberMe');
        var username = this.get('username');
        console.log("cookie toggle");
        if (rememberMe) {
            $.cookie('auth_username', username);
        } else {
            $.removeCookie('auth_username');
        }
}.observes('rememberMe','username') // will fire every time when one of those properties change
```

Comment: Great, that worked. I love a short and to-the-point answer. Thanks. Just out of interest, why wasn't my computed property getting called though? I do recognise now that the observer pattern is more appropriate for what I'm aiming to do but I would have still thought my "hack" would work. :)

Comment: Your computed property would get called, when it is needed, e.g. you call controller.get("cookieToggle"). If no one calls get on your computed property, ember sees no need to call the computed property.